# serach a csv file with comma as delimiter and double quotes as an escape using c++

Tags: c++, csv, boost-tokenizer

basically i am trying to write a code to prompt the user to enter a word knowing that my csv file contains strings as entries and it retrieves all the entries similar to the word prompted by the user.

say the user enters the following word: Younes

and my csv looks like:

name, surname, age, hobby, address
Younes, Thabet, 23, "football,swimming", Chlef
Bilal, Boumad, 23, "chess,jogging", "Tipaza,Boumerdes"
Younes, Mohammed, 20, dance, Algiers

the output should be (only some columns to be displayed):
surname: Thabet
hobby: football,swimming

surname: Mohammed
hobby: dance

preferred **boost token**.

Comment: What is the question? Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: You could search the internet for "c++ parse csv file boost token example".